# rating images in a web page without need to create a new account

Tags: php, jsp, cookies, web, rating

I have a web page that displays images i want to add a rank bar for each image so any one open an image can rate it once without need to create a new account 
, could any one tell me if this is possible or not , i was thinking about using cookies to save the image id inside it so he can rate it once but if another client want to rate the image he can't or if user clear the browser cookies ...  , could any one put me on the right direction or suggest any other method ..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative. If you don't know who your users are, then any user will be able to rank the same image multiple times. You could associate each anonymous user with their own anonymous account with a cookie, and thus make sure that the user only ranks each image once, but if the user uses another machine or browser, or if he clears its anonymous account cookie, you won't be able to do anything.

Just don't use a cookie per image. Use a single anonymous account cookie and remember all the already ranked images for each account in your database, at server-side.